# asp.net MVC parameter not passed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my controller I do have this endpoint:

```
async Task<FileResult> DownloadSelection(AssignedDatabaseSelection selection)
```

And my HTML looks like:

```
@if (Model.AssignedDatabaseSelections.Any())
{
    <table>
        @foreach (var selection in Model.AssignedDatabaseSelections)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@selection.DisplayName</td>
                <td width="10%">
                    @Html.ActionLink(Strings.CsvLabel, "DownloadSelection", "Home", selection, null)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Now I wanted to add another parameter to my controller method:

```
async Task<FileResult> DownloadSelection(AssignedDatabaseSelection selection, DownloadFormat format)
```

And

```
@if (Model.AssignedDatabaseSelections.Any())
{
    <table>
        @foreach (var selection in Model.AssignedDatabaseSelections)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@selection.DisplayName</td>
                <td width="10%">
                    @Html.ActionLink(Strings.CsvLabel, "DownloadSelection", "Home", new {selection = selection, Format = DownloadFormat.CSV}, null)
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    @Html.ActionLink(Strings.ExcelLabel, "DownloadSelection", "Home", new  { selection = selection, Format = DownloadFormat.CSV }, null)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

When I make an inspect elements I got this:

```
<a href="/Home/DownloadSelection?selection=System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.AssignedDatabaseSele_D02B1D7B1220921CC4150FAA016EB8BFD5692B52C49949B0ECB80AA2F98E7355&amp;Format=CSV">Excel</a>
```

Now, the format is filled, but the selection is always null. What am I missing?

Comment: Does your selection work if you do not add the `format` parameter?

Comment: mh, not when I pass it in a new object like new {selection = selection}

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the 2nd parameter. And how are you assigning a `selection`?

Comment: you mean in the view? I read it out of the view model.
so, that would mean I have to make a new view model an passt this one ot the controller?

Comment: but the interessting thing is, that the second parameter is correctly passed, just not the first one.

Comment: If you inspect the link on the browser does it have anything in selection?

Comment: I added the value I get in the inspector of chrome to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you first example, the 3rd parameter is a complex object (typeof `AssignedDatabaseSelections`) and the method will correctly serialize each property of your object to a query string. Note that it only works because your object contains only simple properties.

In the second example, your creating a new object containing a complex object. The `ActionLink()` method (and all methods that generate route/query string values) call the `.ToString()` method on each property in the object (hence you get the name of the class) and do not do recursion.

If you want to pass back all properties of the `AssignedDatabaseSelections` object plus another property, you need to generate a new object containing each property of `AssignedDatabaseSelections`, for example (assuming it contains properties `ID` and `Name`)

```
@Html.ActionLink(Strings.CsvLabel, "DownloadSelection", "Home",
    new { ID = selection.ID, Name = selection.Name, ......, Format = DownloadFormat.CSV }, null)
```

Note that if `AssignedDatabaseSelections` contains a lot of properties and/or larger values, you risk exceeding the query string limit and throwing an exception. A better approach is just to pass the `ID` property of the `AssignedDatabaseSelection` and get the object again in the GET method if you need other properties of it.

```
@Html.ActionLink(Strings.CsvLabel, "DownloadSelection", "Home",
    new { ID = selection.ID, Format = DownloadFormat.CSV }, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to create a link with properties from an object. I am including the code of creating a new Employee within the view but this can/should be in the model:

```
@{ var emp = new Employee { Name = "Tom", Age = 44 }; }
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Test2", "Account", new {Name = emp.Name, Age = emp.Age }, null)
```

Please note how I am passing each property of the `Employee` into the anonymous object for the route values.

The above link will work with this action. The DefaultModeBinder will take the names from the query string in the link and assign it to the properties of the `Employee` and pass it to the action below:

```
public ActionResult Test2(Employee emp)
{
    return null;
}
```